# Show result into input text

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code to calculate results (**multipliers * 5**) , but it shows me results into `<div id="total"></div>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate(multiplier) {
        var product = multiplier*5;
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = product;
    }
</script>

<form>
    <select name="multipliers" onchange="calculate(this.value)">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select> 

    <div id="total"></div> <!-- result is displayed here -->

    <input type="text" id="total" readonly="readonly">

</form>
```

Is it possible to show results into an **input text** not into a div ?

```
    <input type="text" id="total" readonly="readonly"> <!-- I'd like to show result here -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can... try it like this

```
document.getElementById('total').value = product;
```

but it is better to have unique ids.
so remove div if you are not using it anymore
or give another id to textbox

Answer (score 0):

Every element should have a unique identifier, but you have two with `id='total'`. Change the second ID attribute to something unique.